# Adding new clown to a bonded pair

Tags: clownfish

I have 2 black ice ocellaris which are a bonded pair. My original 40 gallon crashed in which they loved the little right corner. They're in QT more because I had them in a friend tank with other fish that aren't same species..  they definitely are sexed as the Smaller one does his submission twitch when she (bigger) comes next to him (smaller).

Soon I'll be introducing them into a 120 gal 48x24x24 with 140lbs of LR..

These clowns won't host, as I had a big bta living right in their territory when I had the 40 gal 4" away. They would only steal food from said BTA, not host. FYI These are tank bred black ice Ocellaris..

I was thinking if I introduced  one or more depending on any advice I get to the new 120 gallon which has NO fish currently until after I QT them (but this means there will be a 3 week establishment of the initial clowns in the 120 gal while the new client will be in QT  (tank has 2 BTA and 1 Long tentacle and torches and frogspawbs etc. currently in it) If I added a new pair or one small juvenile wild caught one (the whole effort is because I want a hosting clown) if the initial clowns have their territory established  then I added a new one to other end of tank at night, would this be possible with the original clowns not hiding and a wild caught definitely would host?

I was also thinking maybe a pair of wild caught juvenile pink skunks which I hear are peaceful but hold their own when mature which are more likely to host anemone then ocellaris are. And again the tank possibly is big enough to have it. Skunks and tomatoes look totally different from their normal clownfish  tear shape etc.

Any advice or ideas would be great!